Building Python shared module on Windows (.pyd) with Cmake using GCC C++ compiler
I'm trying to build a Python shared module on Windows (.pyd) using CMake. I'm working on Windows 11(64 bits), I have MSVC (I use Visual Studio and VS Code) and GCC g++ (downloaded binaries from winlibs.com) C++ compilers. I also have Python 3.12.4 (downloaded from python.org). Among the binaries files downloaded from winlibs.com there is cmake.exe.
The Python shared module I'm trying to build is basically a wrapper for a C++ class (I'm using pybind11). The CMakeLists.txt is very simple, identical to the following mock template
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(Name VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

pybind11_add_module(module_name sources.cpp)
target_include_directories(module_name PRIVATE needed_directories)

When I configure the project for using "Visual Studio 17 2022" generator CMake detects correctly the compiler as MSVC and Python 3.12.4. The built shared module (which has .cp312-win_amd64 in its name) works perfectly, that means the line import module_name doesn't cause any problem when executed in any other .py file. Bellow are the CMake commands I use:
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" ../
cmake --build . --config release

When I configure it for using "MinGW Makefiles" generator CMake also detects correctly the compiler as GCC g++ and Python 3.12.4. The shared module is built (which also has .cp321-win_amd64 in its name) but I can't import it from other .py files, that means the line import module_name causes the following exception
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing module_name: The specified module could not be found.
Bellow are the CMake commands I use
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../
cmake --build . --config release

That is not a problem of wrong directories or folders. Initially I thought it was some Python version incompatibility, now I think I should add some more lines on CMakeLists.txt for the GCC case. Am I right?. I'm new to CMake as well as GCC tools.
Thanks.
I tried to make explicit the Python version I'm using, but as I explained I don't think it has anything to do with Python versions. Since I'm new to both CMake and GCC tools I would like some advices about building with CMake using GCC.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers -- for standard Windows Python releases, you should be using Visual C++ to compile the modules. That's what pip uses to build things, for example.
